# Character set utf8mb3 is not supported by Net Framework

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector

Remote server that hosts my database recently updated MySQL to version 8.0.29. I use Visual Studio 2013 to create a project that utilizes that database. So to summarize my config is: MySQL 8.0.29 on remote location, Visual Studio 2013 locally, MySQL Connector Net 8.0.29 locally, MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8 locally. My remote server has character set set to utf8mb4, collate to utf8mb4_general_ci, also every table character set is utf8mb4. When trying to add new data connection I can't choose any table, but when I provide table name it says that connection succeded. Unfortunately, when I try to look at Tables it throws an error:

```
Character set utf8mb3 is not supported by Net Framework
```

Even thought everything is already set to utf8mb4. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in this bug you should check MySQL bug database at:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107259
It is still unresolved. I had to switch to ODBC connector.

Answer (score 0):

Check information schema, it has a different char set. (utf8mb3)